# Sharepoint 2010 BDC: Connecting to Oracle an using assembly fails

Tags: bdc-model, oracle

I'm trying to make a BDC connection in Sharepoint 2010 to an Oracle Database using an assembly. When unit testing the assembly, it works perfectly, but when using it in the BDC, I get the following exception: 'The provider is not compatible with the version of Oracle client'

The rest of the BDC model works fine; if I return dummy objects instead of actual Oracle results from my assembly, they show up as they should.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I still have no idea why it wouldn't work, but I circumvented the problem by using a WCF service for the BDC connection instead of an assembly.

Suspicions regarding the original cause go towards a 32/64 bit conflict (although compiling everything to 64 bit didn't resolve it) or perhaps a conflict between 64 bit ODP.NET and Win 2k8 (["The 64 bit ODP.NET for Oracle 11 does not work on Win2k8 64 bit."](http://brianhochgurtel.blogspot.com/2010/03/installing-oracle-client-on-64-bit.html))